# How to skip an activity when click device back(not customized) button in another activity

Tags: android, service

I am writing a application where I am dealing with 4 activities, let's say A, B, C & D. Activity A invokes B, B invokes C, C invokes D. On activity C, I have a button called "home" button & and "back" button. When user clicks on home button in the C activity, application should go back to activity B. Here what i want is when i click device back button from activity D it must skip the activity B. Can any one help me.

Comment: read about `intent` and `onBackPressed()`

Comment: [read `launch modes`](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242)

Answer (score 0):

Customize your OnBackPressed method by overriding it,

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(OnetActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```